# Center-align TextView on top of ListFragment with custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, center-align

In [a simple test app at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q38/RotatedList) I am trying to display a user avatar, then two `TextView`s **Username** and **City** (which *should* be center-aligned) and finally the main `ListView` of the [ListFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q38/RotatedList/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/rotatedlist/AccountFragment.java):

[image: screenshot]

In the layout file [fragment_account.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q38/RotatedList/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_account.xml) I try to set `android:textAlignment="center"` for the both `TextView`s (marked by the red arrow in the above screenshot), but that does not have any effect - maybe because the app is for **minSdkLevel=9**?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="#FFF"/>

    <TextView                     <!-- how to center-align? -->
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Username"/>

    <TextView                     <!-- how to center-align? -->
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="City"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please advise, if there is a nice way to center-align those labels.

Comment: Use `android:gravity="center"` instead of `android:textAlignment="center"`

Comment: I tried that one, but missed `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` which is needed too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="#FFF"/>

          <!-- add android:gravity="center" -->
    <TextView                     
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:text="Username"/>

    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:text="City"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` has helped, thanks